# NLog - combining retention days and size limit

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

ASP.NET CORE
Using NLog, I want to achieve the following:

---

log file per day.
File maximum 10MB.
Keep max 30 days of logs, automatically deleting older logs.

---

"MaxArchiveFiles" does not meet this feature requirement

How to configure this?

My current settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
    internalLogLevel="info"
    internalLogFile="C:\Logs\TestProject\nlog-internal.txt">
    <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="ALL"
            fileName="C:\Logs\TestProject\TestProject.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${threadid}|${logger}|${message} ${exception}" 
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveFileName="C:\Logs\TestProject\TestProject.{###}.log"
            archiveAboveSize="10485760"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"
          />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ALL" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need? One clarification: 10Mb is too small, I specify 100Mb, please change it if you want in `archiveAboveSize` field.
e.g.
100MB = 104857600 bytes

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

     <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}" 
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/${cached:${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss}}.log"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive/{#}.log"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" 
            archiveAboveSize="104857600"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            maxArchiveDays="30" /> 
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: YES, "maxArchiveDays" seems to be version 4.7, mine is 4.6X, need to study

Comment: So, you can  use maxArchivFiles but then if in one day your logs are increase archiveAboveSize then you will lose data from some days. You can refuse from max file size. And use  archiveNumbering="Date" with maxArchivFiles

Comment: As long as "maxArchiveDays" is used, LOG cannot be generated

Comment: NLog 4.7 RC1 (or newer is required). See also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.7.0-rc1

Comment: I ended up using "NLog 4.7 RC1" and successfully solved the problem